# XSLT stylesheets design pattern - separate common and specific templates in different stylesheets

Tags: design-patterns, xslt, fxsl

I was wondering if there is a good approach in XSLT stylesheet design pattern to separate common and specific data representation.

I was trying, but got very confused and lost. I would appreciate any advice, tips, hints where I can read up on how to better separate XSLT stylesheets. And also, would really appreciate help with the example below as it doesn't work =/ THANK YOU!

I need to create a variety of HTML docs with different looks that would reuse some of the data. For example date of a document, signature details (name, job title) and so on. Also, I'm using quite a lot of global variables (because XML isn't structured well and data reused throughout a doc).

What I was trying to do, is to move all the templates that would create a common HTML structure in one stylesheet and then all specific bits will be in their own stylesheet.

Something like the following:

Common templetes stylesheet "commonTemplates.xsl"

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<!-- Variables Local -->
...

<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/Bookings">
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- populated by a template in a specific stylesheet -->
            <title><xsl:call-template name="docTitle"/></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- general template for date -->
<xsl:template match="/Bookings/Booking" name="docDate">
  <p class="date"><xsl:value-of select="./@Date"/></p>
</xsl:template>

<!-- general template for signature -->
<xsl:template match="/Bookings/Booking/Users" name="signature">
    <xsl:param name="signatureLine" select="'Yours sincerely,'"/>
    <div id="signature">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="$signatureLine"/></p>
        <p class="details">
            <!-- populated by a template in a specific stylesheet -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="signature"/>
        </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<!-- dummy templates signatures otherwise it complains that there is no such template -->
<xsl:template name="docTitle"/>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Specific templetes stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<!-- Imports -->
<xsl:import href="commonTemplates.xsl"/>

<!-- BODY CONTENT OF HTML PAGE -->
<xsl:template match="/Bookings/Booking">
    <xsl:call-template name="docDate"/>
    <!-- document's content -->
    <div>
        <xsl:call-template name="content" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="docTitle">
    <xsl:text>Here is the document title</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- some content at the end of which signature should be inserted -->
<xsl:template name="content">
    <p>SOME CONTENT</p>        
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<!-- specific rule to insert appropriate data for signature -->
<xsl:template match="/Bookings/Booking/Users" mode="signature">
    <span class="name"><xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/></span>
    <span class="job"><xsl:value-of select="./@Title"/></span>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, the template for signature doesn't work and I can't figure out why :( It does for the docTitle though.

The results HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>      
      <p class="date">16 February 2010</p>
      <div id="secondDeposit">
         <p>SOME CONTENT</p>
         <!-- here I get lots of empty space -->
      </div>    
   </body>
```

I was wondering if such idea could be implemented in general and how to do it properly, obviously mine doesn't work.

Also, which approach will be better in this case: include or import stylesheet? I think with one of them I don't need to list all the variables again.

I would appreciate any help! Sorry for a long post and if it's not as clear.

Thank you!

Comment: @Tomalak, thank you for editing the HTML. Couldn't figure out how to do it :( Thanks!

Comment: Oh dear... just realised that I didn't have element in my test XML. I do apologize!

Nevertheless, would love to hear what approach people use in similar situations: how better to separate common and specific templates between several stylesheets.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I use the following method:

**Template File** (/templates/Main.xslt)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:include href="../functions/General.xslt"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xml:lang="en">
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
         Template Content
         <xsl:call-template name="PageContent" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Functions File** (/functions/General.xslt)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Generic functions used in the site go in here -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Page File** (/default.xslt)

There will be a few of these to define different layouts within the template. This is the XSLT file you call when doing your transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="templates/Main.xslt" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-imports />
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <xsl:template name="PageContent">
      <!-- Put your specific page stuff here -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

**It is a recommended best practive to accumulate commonly used templates in stylesheet files** that will be imported by specific XSLT applications. Collections of such useful xstylesheet files make useful **libraries**.

Of course, a stylesheet module that is imported often imports other stylesheet modules.

An example is the [**FXSL library**](http://fxsl.sf.net) for functional programming in XSLT. Do look into how XSLT applications (the example testxxx.xsl files) import the functionality they need.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, Thank for the link. I've tried to look into examples, but I got lost in them =/ Maybe, you know some articles or any reading for beginners?

Many thanks!

Comment: @Daria This is the link to an FXSL 1.x article (FXSL for XSLT 1.0): http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2003/Novatchev01/EML2003Novatchev01.html

And this is a link to an FXSL 2.x article (FXSL for XSLT 2.0):

http://web.archive.org/web/20070222111927/http://www.idealliance.org/papers/extreme/proceedings/xslfo-pdf/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.pdf